# Acumatica Fill field from other field

Tags: field, standards, acumatica

I need to fill a field "description" from other field in a screen Acumatica.
The problem is that one of the other field contains the identifier of the DAC but I have to retrieve the description and not the identifier.

I tried to do this with a Fluent BQL query in an Event Handler in order to retrieve the single result.
var Feurname = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APInvoice.vendorID>>>>.Select(this, **BAccount.acctName**).First().GetItem();

I have the following error when I test the code :
\App_RuntimeCode\APInvoiceEntry.cs(97): error CS0119: 'BAccount.acctName' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

\App_RuntimeCode\APInvoiceEntry.cs(97): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PXSelectBase.Select(params object[])'

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I succeeded by writing the query with LINQ instead of BQL with the following code in the event Handler.
Thanks to the contributors.
I would be curious to know to do the same with BQL/F-BQL.

var row = e.Row;
VendorMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance();
var query1 = (from p in graph.Select() where p.BAccountID == row.VendorID select p.AcctName).ToList();
string feurname = "";
if (query1.Count > 0)
{ feurname = Convert.ToString(query1[0]); }
else
{ feurname = ""; }
row.DocDesc = feurname;

Comment: This is not encouraged in when you can get data from a BQL query. Since you can get data from BQL or fluent BQL, you should use that. Try to fix the error in BQL query

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the whole BAccount object and then take the AcctName properties value instead.
So it will be something like below:

```
BAccount account = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APInvoice.vendorID>>>>.Select(this);
var Feurname = (account?.AcctName)?? "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done couple of mistakes here,

1. When you need to pass a value to `PXSelect<>`, you should not pass types (*starting with a simple letter*). You should pass the DAC property name (*starting with a capital letter*). In your case BAccount.acctName is the type and property is BAccount.AcctName. Therefore the error message is correct.
2. In your `PXSelect<>` query, you have not specified any field with `Required<>`. You have only specified fields with `Current<>`. You only need to pass parameters to `.Select(this, ...)` if you have `Required<>` in your `PXSelect<>`. If you have `Current<>`, framework will auto replace current value, then you don't need to pass parameters.

Both solutions below will return the BAccount Object:

1. Assuming that your `APInvoice` has current values loaded. then remove the BAccount.acctName.

```
var Feurname = PXSelect<BAccount,Where<BAccount.bAccountID,Equal<Current<APInvoice.vendorID>>>>.Select(this);
```

2. If your `APInvoice` current is not set, then you can pass the parameter to load `BAccount`. By replacing it with `Required<>`, then pass the correct parameter to `Select(this, ...)`.

```
var Feurname = PXSelect<BAccount,Where<BAccount.bAccountID,Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this, ...Parameter here...);
```

Comment: I just want to retrieve the value of the field BAccount.AcctName but I don't need to pass parameters. I should have only 1 row as a result of the query with the current value.          
 var Feurname = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APInvoice.vendorID>>>>.Select(this);  -->Error is CS0120 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property PXSelectBase<BAccount>.Select(params object[])'

Comment: @LionelPARIS Please provide more information on your primary DAC, Graph and, view of APInvoice (if it is not the primary DAC)

Comment: I added the event handler in an extension of the APInvoice Graph. I don’t have modified anything else In the DAC nor in the graph.